# <video> tag makes my button invisible

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, material-design

So this is an odd one. I'm sure it has something to do with layering of objects, but honestly, I'm a bit baffled.

Problem:

 I have a div, inside of which I have a video element, then below that element I have a button, wrapped in an li in a ul. If I comment out the `<video>` my button appears at the bottom of the page. (note: the `<ul>` is a bootstrap `class="pager navbar-fixed-bottom"`). When the video is included the button is still there, just invisible. That is to say, I can click on it, but it is totally transparent. If I drag the element, it drags and you can see the 'NEXT' that should be the text on the button, so it is still there.

What I have tried:

I have tried to set the `z-index` of the button (set to 500 to no avail). I have used both -

```
<video src='soatehohu' controls></video>
```

and

```
<video src='soaehusoe' controls/>
```

and I have but divs around both the video and the button tags independently, but that did nothing. I'm honestly not sure what could possibly be happening to make a button invisible but still usable.

Note: I am using both bootstrap and the button is a material design lite button.

Edit: (Exact Code with ids changed)

```
<div id="videoContainer">
  <div>
    <video id="video" src="source#t=82,223" controls/>
  </div>
  <br>
  <ul class="pager navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <li>
      <button id="nextButton" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect">Next</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think we will need to see more markup, not just the `<video>` tag, but the actual `ul`, `li`, button, etc to help out.

Comment: @JohnnyCoder - Edited to reflect that.

Comment: can you replicate this in a plunker or something similar?

Comment: z-index only works if position is set to relative or absolute. other than that not much we can do to help without seeing the page live.

Comment: @AndyRay - navbar-fixed-bottom in bootstrap sets the contents to be position:absolute already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to have `navbar-fixed-bottom` for your pager? It sets an absolute position, and if you have a div with that class that has *both* your video and pager component, it's going to float on top of the video.

[Here'](http://codepen.io/dlochrie/pen/aBxKZJ)s an example of your pager below a video *without* `navbar-fixed-bottom`, which should work for you.

Comment: This did fix the problem, but I have consistent pagers across all of my pages, all of which sit at the  navbar-fixed-bottom  position. Is there a reason why the video element is eating the  navbar-fixed-bottom  ? They aren't anywhere near each other, as far as screen placement goes.

Comment: As long as both the `<video>` and the `<div class="navbar-fixed-bottom">` are in the _same_ parent `div`, the absolute positioning of the `navbar-fixed-bottom` is going to position itself _relative_ to the parent `div`. Also, if this answer fixed your issue, please accept it as the correct answer :-)

Comment: But why does that video have this effect? It seems to be the only tag to do this. I have multiple other divs where I have a paragraph or similar above the navbar-fixed-bottom, and they all act the same as each other, which tacks them to the bottom of my body. None of them are positioned relative to their actual div. Not to mention, why does video make it invisible? You'll notice, that in my question, the button is in the same location (outside of the div, at the bottom of the body), just invisible. I can still click on it while it is invisible. So, it fixed the invisibility, not my problem.

Comment: Good question, but this goes much deeper than I can help you. For example, what is the default CSS stylings for your `div`s and for `video`? Bootstrap comes with a `normalize` library, so what is that doing to the styles for those elements? The basic issue here is that no matter how your elements are playing together, you are using an absolutely positioned div/element in the same place you have the video, which you have NOT absolutely positioned. The video is a block element, your `navbar-fixed-bottom` has an absolute position, and has lost its block attributes.